# insert java date time into Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Oracle date format on server is `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS`

I would like to insert a variable which contains a date with timestamp into Oracle date column.

I am getting error while inserting date into Oracle "date column ends before format picture ends".

All I want is append specific timestamp to java string date and insert that string/date format into Oracle database

example:

```
String incoming_date = request.getParameter("insert_date"); //this comes as a string in dd-mon-yyyy format

formatted_incoming_date = incoming_date + " 00:00:01"; //I want to append time factor to above variable with 00:00:01

insert into testtable values(formatted_incoming_date);
```

Comment: Can you show the real code. ? You use JDBC? JPA ?

Comment: I am using JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this

`insert into testtable values(TO_DATE (formatted_incoming_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss);`

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to insert date as a string? It seems like there is an implicit conversion from string to date in Oracle. Can `java.sql.Date` be used instead?

Anyway, as long as date comes in format `dd-mon-yyyy` you have to convert it either into `java.sql.Date` object or in proper for Oracle string representation as `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS` i.e.
incoming date `"05-12-2016"` string for Oracle `"12/05/2016 00:00:00"`

Comment: I want to define my own time stamp, not "12/05/2016 00:00:00". You can refer my question

Comment: Whatever, define it in proper to Oracle format if you'd like to insert it as String into Date column or use java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp as Insert parameter type instead.